# not working @extends() use query in laravel

Tags: laravel

i try to display data with id, but problem is when just:

```php
    public function category()
    {            
        return view('font.category.category');            
    }
```

`@extends()` blade is working. I try to query use this:

```php
    function  public function category($id)
    {
        $pCategoryById = Menu::where('id', $id)->get();

        return view('font.category.category', 'pCategoryById'=>$pCategoryById]);            
    }
```

`@extends()` blade is not working how to solve it? url is `{{url('/category/'.$result->id)}}` web is: `Route::get("/category/{id}",'fontController@category');`.

Comment: Can you please let us know the Laravel version and code?

Comment: It would be helpful to also see the code in your view since there is no reason why `@extends` would work in the first example and not in the second from just this code.

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.8.23

Comment: when url is http://localhost/work1/category its working but when use id url http://localhost/work1/category/1 its not working

Answer (score 0):

in url

```
{{url('/category',$result->id)}}
```

in controller

```
$pCategoryById=Menu::find($id);
return view('font.category.category',compact('pCategoryById'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the url,

```
{{url('/category',$result->id)}}
```

Or you can use as like,

```
{{url('/')}}/{{$result->id}}
```

In the Controller,

```
$pCategoryById=Menu::where('id',$id)->get();
return view('font.category.category',compact($pCategoryById));
```

If @extends() is not working, then you have to check the right path which is extended.